# Understanding MySQL key_len in Explain Statement

Tags: mysql

According to [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html#explain_key_len), the `key_len` column indicates the length of the key that MySQL decided to use. The length is `NULL` if the key column says `NULL`. Note that the value of key_len enables you to determine how many parts of a multiple-part key MySQL actually uses.

Using an example from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580685/mysql-why-does-an-order-by-id-runs-much-slower-than-order-by-other-columns), I have an EXPLAIN SELECT statement that shows MySQL using an `Index` with `key_len: 6`. Below shows the composition of the index and columns used.

```
`Type` char(1) NOT NULL,
`tn` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'l',
`act` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`flA` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
KEY `Index` (`Type`, `tn`, `act`, `flA`)
```

So how does the value of `key_len` allows me to determine that my query uses the first three parts of a multiple-part key?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The key_len specifies the number of bytes that MySQL uses from the key.
Indexes are always used left_to_right. i.e. only the left-most part is used.

The length of your fields is as follows:

```
1 byte             `Type` char(1) NOT NULL,
1 byte             tn char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'l',
1 byte             act tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
3 bytes            flA mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
1+1+1+3 = 6 bytes  KEY `Index` (`Type`, `tn`, `act`, `flA`)
 key usage always starts here ---^^^^^
```

If the key_len = 3 then it's using `type+tn+act`.
Note that Key_len = 4 is impossible in this configuration.

Comment: `mediumint` is 3 bytes if i remember well.

Comment: @ypercube, you are quite correct, the weirdness of a 3-byte int type got the better of me.

Comment: @ All, 3 bytes for [mediumint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) is correct.

Comment: One more question, why do I get a `NULL` in the `ref` column instead of `const,const,const,const`?

Comment: Does the size change if the column is nullable?

Comment: what if key_len = 16?